# Google App Engine cron job not showing up

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, cron, serverless

I created a Google Cloud function that gets data and dumps it into a Google SQL Database.  I need this function to execute every 15 minutes.  As I understand it you cannot execute cloud functions in a cron job.  The workaround is to deploy an app in the App engine.

I've deployed a simple NodeJS application that makes an http request using the NodeJS https module.  I've deployed this app to Google App Engine along with the following cron.yaml

```
cron:
- description: "Gets new data every 15 minutes"
  url: /
  schedule: every 15 mins
```

But this is not executing and it is not showing up in the cron jobs list.  Does the above cron job syntax look correct?

Is there anything else I need to do to get Google App Engine to pick up this cron job?

tyia

Comment: If the cron job doesn't show up in the cron jobs list it means it wasn't actually deployed. How did you deploy it?

Comment: I have all the files, index.js, package.json, app.yaml, and cron.yaml all in the same folder.  I am deploying all of them using gcloud app deploy from inside that directory

Answer (score 38, accepted):

I had mistakingly thought that cron.yaml would be deployed as a cron job when I executed gcloud app deploy

To deploy the cron job I had to explicitly deploy cron.yaml

```
gcloud app deploy cron.yaml
```

Comment: Yup, even in the earlier days (with the GAE SDK) deploying with the rest of the app wasn't always working, now it's not even mentioned in the documentation anymore.

Comment: You are not the only one :)

Comment: This is a very important post, as this info is mentioned nowhere else.  Thank you!

Comment: how is this _nowhere_ on the documentation?

Comment: Same problem, thank you very much!